# Disconnecting the database connection while running rufus-scheduler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rufus-scheduler

I have a scenario as,

I am collecting the online devices/units on the server at everyday for at 12. For this I have written job in the my controller. Currently I used **.at** method for testing. here is my controller code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'fileutils'
require "time"
require "date"

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.at '2014/05/09 9:35:00' do
  autoupdates = AutoupdatesController.new
  autoupdates.get_all_online_units
end

class AutoupdatesController < ApplicationController    
  def get_all_online_units
    # logic for getting online units
  end    
end
```

scheduler running fine but it disconnects my database connection. Also I checked if I just initialize scheduler object that time also it is braking. 
 It gives **Can't connect to MySQL server** error. After restarting the server it works fine.

For this I am using `rails 3.2.11, ruby 1.8.7 and rufus-scheduler 3.0.7`
How can I resolve this issue.

**Edit**
Now I have created a separate file in *`config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb`*. 
Here is my file content

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'fileutils'
require "time"
require "date"

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.at '2014/05/08 1:25:00' do
    Rails.logger.info("#-----------In the config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb-----------#")
end
```

Then after starting the server it is giving me same type of error

```
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.11 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
Exiting
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `connect': Can't connect to MySQL server on 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com' (4) (Mysql2::Error)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.14/lib/mysql2/client.rb:67:in `initialize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `new'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter.rb:16:in `mysql2_connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:315:in `new_connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:325:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:247:in `checkout'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `loop'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:242:in `checkout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:239:in `checkout'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:102:in `connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:101:in `connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:410:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:171:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:145:in `connection'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/model_schema.rb:308:in `clear_cache!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:97:in `_callback_before_3'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:418:in `_run__321316982__prepare__4__callbacks'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:74:in `prepare!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:48:in `prepare!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:47
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `send'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.2.11/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /home/pdcadmin/deploy/pdc-dashboard/config/environment.rb:5
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /home/pdcadmin/deploy/pdc-dashboard/config.ru:3
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /home/pdcadmin/deploy/pdc-dashboard/config.ru:0:in `new'
    from /home/pdcadmin/deploy/pdc-dashboard/config.ru:0
```

Then I commented some lines from the task_scheduler.rb file Here is that file

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus/scheduler'
require 'net/ssh'
require 'fileutils'
require "time"
require "date"
=begin
scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.at '2014/05/08 1:25:00' do
          Rails.logger.info("#-----------In the config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb-----------#")
end
=end
```

and again started server it works fine.

**Edit 2** Here is my config.ru file

```
# This file is used by Rack-based servers to start the application.

require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run MyApp::Application
```

Comment: rufus-scheduler DOES NOT disconnect the connection to your database. Take a look at its source code, you'll see nothing about database connection in there. Do rephrase your issue, especially its title.

Comment: I have changed title.

Comment: The text is unclear. When does the "can't connect to MySQL error" happens? Could you please add the complete error trace?

Comment: Some logs please , it would be helpful too .

Comment: The complete error trace please.

Comment: What does your config.ru looks like?
What happens if you comment out the content of the scheduler "at" block?
What happens if you comment out the three lines from "schedule.at" to "end"?
Does the error happen after a first request to port 3000 or does it happen immediately?
Does the "#----In the config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb" message appear in the log, yes or no?

Comment: issue aeries after initializing `scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new` and yes it prints "#----In the config/initializer/task_scheduler.rb" in the log

Comment: Thanks for the config.ru. Thanks for the answer to my last question. Could please answer my two "what happens if" questions?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help: http://new-bamboo.co.uk/blog/2010/04/11/automatic-reconnection-of-mysql-connections-in-active-record

Your text is not clear, when does the "can't connect to MySQL" error happens? When rufus-scheduler calls your get_all_online_units?

Comment: also I just checked I removed my job and only initialize `Rufus::Scheduler` object at that time also it is breaking.

Comment: Sorry, what you write makes no sense. We cannot read your mind. http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

Comment: I removed my scheduler job and just just keep `scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.start_new`and if I call any action of that controller then it is breaking. If I remove it then it is working fine.

Comment: Please fill in these details in the body of your issue. Please add the error trace in the body of your issue.

Comment: sorry for your inconvenience but I looked into the logs, I didn't get any specific issue. But I have added some application trace here please look into it.

Comment: one quick question I have used ruby 1.8.7 and rufus-scheduler 3.0.7. dose that version matters here.

Comment: well, Ruby 1.8.7 is getting old. Nowadays, people start projects with 1.9.x or even 2.1.x.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52362/discussion-between-user2622247-and-jmettraux)

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to chat.

Comment: no problem I will work on it after sometime. Thanks for you co-operation.